# Is it better to check for a difference between two small objects or update their properties without checking in an Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, performance

In my Angular 13 app I keep some metada for a certain type of object used in my application in Local Storage. It's an array of simple, 3 property objects. The array is not big, the length is not bigger than 20-30. The properties are simple types, not nested objects or anything like that.

I am listening for changes in my app's store. Due to user actions two out of 3 properties can change. My question is, what is more efficient:

updating those properties right off the bat without checking if a change occured (the update will update changed values and reassign unchanged values to same value)

```
objectsFromTheStoreForWhichChangesOccured.forEach((object, index) => {
          metadataFromLocalStorage[index].property1 = object.property1;
          metadataFromLocalStorage[index].property2 = object.property2;
      })
```

vs.

checking if a change occured and updating a property only then?

```
objectsFromTheStoreForWhichChangesOccured.forEach((object, index) => {
        if (metadataFromLocalStorage[index].property1 != object.property1) {
          metadataFromLocalStorage[index].property1 = object.property1;
        }
        if (metadataFromLocalStorage[index].property2 != object.property2) {
          metadataFromLocalStorage[index].property2 = object.property2;
        }
      })
```

I know that in my case the difference in two approaches is probably very small but I wonder which approach is more efficient in this case. Maybe in case of such a small object updating it without checking the difference is going to be quicker?

Answer (score 0):

I highly advise you to use the first approach. Assignation is cheap in js/ts and it will make your code cleaner.

If you look at benchmark, a comparison takes almost exactly the same amount of time as an assignment https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/8807/0/comparison-versus-assignment#latest_results_block

However you are doing a comparison, then potentially an assignment, so on average, your code will be slower with the checks.

It's possible the compiler is actually checking first, but this kind of optimization that are always applicable (you can always check before assigning) are better left for the compiler to optimize.

In general it's extremely important to keep clean code, and your checks add some useless complexity so it's inadvisable.